# Django 1.10 IntegrityError on register

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a registration page and I have a model CafeUser which serves as the profile for the User model. I used a tutorial to set up a signal receiver so I could create a CafeUser for all new registered users.

models.py:

```
class CafeUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name="cafeuser")
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    birth_date = models.DateField('birthdate')

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name + " " + self.user.last_name



@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        CafeUser.objects.create(user=instance)
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.cafeuser.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.cafeuser.phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            user.save()

            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('cafe:index')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'cafe/register.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Rquired.')
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)
```

When I try testing the registration, the user is created, however, the CafeUser is not:

> IntegrityError at /register/ null value in column "birth_date"
>   violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7, 8,
>   null, ).

register.html:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Please let me know how to fix this and any other tips you might have for improving this unit of code.

Comment: Can you please post the form part of the html? It sounds like birth_date isn't being sent properly.

Comment: what's the result of `form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')` ? I think there is `null` value that's why you are getting this error

Comment: It's better to add additional information to the actual question rather than through comments :)

Comment: my bad, i've added it to the op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CafeUser was not saving. Based on what I read in the docs somewhere, I had thought that calling `user.save()` was supposed to automatically call `save()` on the profile module as well - and I'm still not sure why it doesn't. So I just wrote the call `user.cafeuser.save()` myself anyway:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()

        user.cafeuser.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
        user.cafeuser.phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        user.cafeuser.save() # Apparently this had to be added
        user.save()

        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('cafe:index')
```